# How to resize a png image programmatically in xcode iOS6

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, image-resizing

I have a png image in a xib, and I resize it in the viewDidLoad method depending on the size I need:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
...

    self.png.image = [[self.png image] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(200, 20, 300, 20)];

    self.png.frame = CGRectMake(16, 19, 320, 463);

   ...
}
```

This worked ok in iOS5, but when I try it on iOS6 it does not resize the png image.

I've tried with:

```
 self.png.image = [[self.png image] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(149,170, 200, 149) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
```

And it doesn't work, I've tried it in the - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews method and it doesn't work, I have the Autolayout disabled. How can I resize the image for iOS 6?

Comment: are you sure that the xib imageview is connected to the iboutlet..?

Comment: yes, it is connected
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *png;

Comment: Ok, I know where is the problem now... the image loaded in iOS6 is the @2x version, and the resolution is different, so the frame is different, but I don't know how to solve it. How can I detect which version of the image is loaded?